# ASP.NET C# With list navigation how to set id="current" on active navigation page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm still learning asp.net and wanted to know if there was a simple way to set the id="current" to the navigation bar so that depending on the page a user was on it would highlight that page. My template is set up to use the id="current" to change the style of the link and I have i class to set the style of each tab.

Here is the code in my Site.Master

```
<nav id="navigation" class="style-1">

<div class="left-corner"></div>
<div class="right-corner"></div>

<ul class="menu" id="responsive">

    <li><a href="home.aspx" id="current"><i class="home"></i> Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="Calendar.aspx"><i class="calendar"></i>Calendar</a></li>

    <li><a href="Bill.aspx"><i class="list"></i>Bills</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Like I said, I'm still learning so i'm not sure if it would be better to place it in a ContentPlaceHolder. I tried to just request the URL and do if statements but I wasn't sure how to set the id=.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into setting the `class` of your menu items rather than the `id` in order to display it as highlighted.

You can do something as so.
Add an `id` and `runat="server"` to each of your links:

```
<li><a href="home.aspx" id="HomeLink" runat="server"><i class="home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Calendar.aspx" id="CalendarLink" runat="server"><i class="calendar"></i>Calendar</a></li>
<li><a href="Bill.aspx" id="BillLink" runat="server"><i class="list"></i>Bills</a></li>
```

Then in the code-behind of your master page, you can set the classes to each as they're navigated to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCurrentPage();
}

private void SetCurrentPage()
{
    var pageName = GetPageName();

    switch (pageName)
    {
        case "home.aspx":
            HomeLink.Attributes["class"] = "current";
            break;
        case "Calendar.aspx":
            CalendarLink.Attributes["class"] = "current";
            break;
        case "Bill.aspx":
            BillLink.Attributes["class"] = "current";
            break;
    }
}

private string GetPageName()
{
    return Request.Url.ToString().Split('/').Last();
}
```

This will set the class of link that matches your current page to `current`.  Of course you will need to define that class in your style sheet.  But this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I ended up using and it works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great practice to set ids programmatically in controls... It depends on how you want to determine the 'current' or active state.

If you are using ASP.NET forms, you could look into using the Menu ASP.NET controls, which assigns a class to the 'active' item and can be paired/databound with an ASP.NET Sitemap.

If you would prefer not to use ASP.NET forms, you could put a function evaluation in the href tag, and declare the function in the ASP.NET Master PAge's code behind. Something like

```
<a href="home.aspx" class="<% CurrentOrNot("home") %>"> ...
```

Then declare a function that returns a string:

```
public void CurrentOrNot(string navItem)
{
    //Do evaulation on URL to determine if we're on the current one or not.
    //pseudocode: if(navItem == Current.Url) return "mycssclassthatiscurrentnav"; else "";

}
```

Check into the ASP.NET Menu before you roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

this is Probably not the best answer, But i recently tried to do something similar to what you are trying. First I set a variable to represent the css class for each menu link, then I get the current file path and check to see if it contains the location, and then set the css class based on whether or not the page is the active one.

```
 @{
            //some how find out what page we are on so we can set the active attribute
            var HomeClass = "non-active";
            var AboutClass = "non-active";

            string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath;
            if (path.Contains("Home"))
            {
                HomeClass = "active";
            }
            if (path.Contains("About"))
            {
                AboutClass = "active";
            }



    }
```

Then for the menu I did this for the class attributes

```
<a href="/home" class="@HomeClass"></a>
< a href="/about" class=@AbouitClass"> </a>
```

Comment: This was my original idea. Let me play with this and let you know how it goes.