# Save the <LI> Class value on Site.master postback event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I wanted to change class of `<LI>` on click, which I managed to do with jquery (I'm Newbie in jquery)

The Code:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
         $('#Mymenu li').click(function () {
              $('li.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's work Perfectly. That Jquery code above removes class of an li and assign it to other, but once redirect/postback occurs its lost the value and back to the default value.

any Idea thanks

Comment: how would you expect value will be the same after post-back ?

Comment: I'm newbie on jquery, and yes :) some of my research say that I need to save to the cookie the value crated by jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store value of currently selected li in cookie,localStorage or window hash and retrive the value on page reload.

check out window hash example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $('li.active').click(function () {
                //tweak this line

                window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
               $("li.active").removeClass("active")
               $(this).addClass('active');
           });
           var hash = window.location.hash;
          $("#"+hash).removeClass("active")
               $("#"+hash).addClass('active');
       });
</script>
```

**Update**
Check out the complete example

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('li').click(function () {
                //tweak this line

                window.location.hash = $(this).index();
                $("li.active").removeClass("active")
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            var suffix = window.location.hash.match(/\d+/);
            $("li:eq(" + suffix + ")").removeClass("active")
            $("li:eq(" + suffix + ")").addClass('active');
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .active {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>A
                </li>
                <li>B
                </li>
                <li>C                </li>
                <li>D
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but is not working,.                                                `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#mymenu li').click(function () {
                //tweak this line

                window.location.hash = $(this).attr('id');
                $("li.active").removeClass("active")
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            var hash = window.location.hash;
            $("#" + hash).removeClass("active")
            $("#" + hash).addClass('active');
        });
</script>`

Comment: same issue sir , looklike it wipeout the value, to be simple I created a new project with a menu, and I put your code and the same problem, working good when no redirect/postback. thanks

Comment: Thanks sir Also working, your query code :) you save my time.  Different implementation but both working ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who comments to my question, I got the better solution of this issue base on this site:

[ASP.NET C# With list navigation how to set id=“current” on active navigation page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690583/asp-net-c-sharp-with-list-navigation-how-to-set-id-current-on-active-navigatio)

Based on the my researched I need to  set it manually in the Page_Load event:

here the code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetCurrentPage();
}

private void SetCurrentPage()
{
    var pageName = GetPageName();

    switch (pageName)
    {
        case "home.aspx":
            HomeLink.Attributes["class"] = "current";
            break;
        case "Calendar.aspx":
            CalendarLink.Attributes["class"] = "current";
            break;
        case "Bill.aspx":
            BillLink.Attributes["class"] = "current";
            break;
    }
}

private string GetPageName()
{
    return Request.Url.ToString().Split('/').Last();
}
```

it's working perfectly right now.

Comment: thanks for clearing.. As I wrote on my comments "set it manually in the Page_Load event". thanks anyways you give the reader more knowingness. God Bless.